# Using Jackson with Optional to generate Optional.empty() when field is missing

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I am using Jackson to convert a json string to java object. I have an Optional field in my class. Whenever I try to deserialize a string which is missing the optional field, it is generating `null` for that field instead of `Optional.empty()`.

Below is the code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        Person1 p1 = mapper.readValue("{\"name\": \"harsh\"}", Person1.class);
        System.out.println(p1);
    }
}
```

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public class Person1 {
    public final String name;
    public final Optional<Integer> age;

    public Person1(String name, Optional<Integer> age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

It generate following output:

```
Person1(name=harsh, age=null)
```

However, I want it to generate:

```
Person1(name=harsh, age=Optional.empty)
```

I have also tried adding `OptionalIntegerDeserializer` customer deserializer as below, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public class Person1 {
    public final String name;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = OptionalIntegerDeserializer.class)
    public final Optional<Integer> age;

    public Person1(String name, Optional<Integer> age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static class OptionalIntegerDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Optional<Integer>> {
        public OptionalIntegerDeserializer() {
            super(Optional.class);
        }

        @Override
        public Optional<Integer> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            JsonNode node = p.readValueAsTree();
            if (node.isNull()) {
                return Optional.empty();
            } else {
                return Optional.of(node.intValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way we can generate `Optional.empty` instead of `null` for the missing field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person {
    
    private String name;
    
    @JsonDeserialize(using = OptinalDeserializer.class)
    @Builder.Default
    private Optional<Integer> age = Optional.empty();
}
```

Custom deserialization is

```
public class OptionalIntegerDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Optional<Integer>> {

    protected OptionalIntegerDeserializer() {
        super(Optional.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Integer> deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) {
        if (parser.getValueAsInt() > 0 ) {
            return Optional.of(parser.getValueAsInt());
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

First test

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String s = "{\"name\": \"harsh\"}";
    Person p = JsonMapper.builder().build().readValue(s, Person.class);

    System.out.println(p);
 }
```

Output1 is: `Person(name=harsh, age=Optional.empty)`

Second test

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String s = "{\"name\": \"harsh\", \"age\": 19}";
    Person p = JsonMapper.builder().build().readValue(s, Person.class);

    System.out.println(p);
 }
```

Output2 is: `Person(name=harsh, age=Optional[19])`

I tried it and it works, would you try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks. It is working now with the default value.

Comment: After adding default value for the Optional field, seems like we don't even need `OptionalIntegerDeserializer` custom deserializer. It is working fine without that as well.

Comment: I let the custom deserializer because if you want do another logic during the deserialization.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.